# class factory error when test a COM server

Tags: com, atl

I am implementing a COM component

```
import "unknwn.idl";
[
    uuid(CF86E2E0-B12D-4C6A-9C5A-D7AA65101E91),
]
coclass CClassic
{
   [default] interface IClassic;
}
[
  object,
  uuid(CF86E2E0-B12D-4C6A-9C5A-D7AA65101E90),
  pointer_default(unique),
  oleautomation
]
interface IClassic : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT Hello();
}
```

and encapsulated it in an in-process dll and an out-of-process exe respectively.

In the dll case , I can call the interface method successfully.

But in the exe case, got the `80040154` error. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/com/building-and-registering-a-proxy-dll?redirectedfrom=MSDN) doc, I registered the proxy and checked the registry, all the needed registry keys/values are there.

How does this happen? I doubt something is missing in the above idl file. Many thanks!!!

#### Update

comexe.cpp

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
/*
cl /nologo /EHsc comexe.cpp comobj.cpp classic/classic_i.c /link /debug
cl /nologo /EHsc /DREGISTER_PROXY_DLL classic/classic_p.c classic/classic_i.c classic/dlldata.c /link /dll /out:comproxy.dll /export:DllGetClassObject /export:DllCanUnloadNow /export:DllRegisterServer /export:DllUnregisterServer /export:GetProxyDllInfo rpcrt4.lib
*/
struct MyModule : CAtlExeModuleT<MyModule>
{
  HRESULT RegisterClassObjects(
        _In_ DWORD dwClsContext,
        _In_ DWORD dwFlags)
    {
    auto hr = CAtlExeModuleT::RegisterClassObjects(dwClsContext,dwFlags);
    printf("RegisterClassObjects 0x%x\n",hr);
    return hr;
    }

    HRESULT RegisterServer(
        _In_ BOOL bRegTypeLib = FALSE,
        _In_opt_ const CLSID* pCLSID = NULL)
    {
        auto hr = CAtlExeModuleT::RegisterServer(false, pCLSID);
        if(FAILED(hr))
          printf("Toaster register failed 0x%x\n",hr);
        return hr;
    }
};

MyModule mod;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
  mod.WinMain(SW_HIDE);
}
```

comobj.cpp

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <typeinfo>
//#include "comobj.h"
#include "classic/classic.h"

CComModule _Module;
extern "C" CLSID CLSID_CClassic;

struct Toast : CComObjectRoot,CComCoClass<Toast,&CLSID_CClassic>,IClassic
{
  DECLARE_REGISTRY(CLSID_CClassic,"Toaster.1.0","Toaster","Toast Server",THREADFLAGS_BOTH);
  DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY();
  DECLARE_OBJECT_DESCRIPTION("Toast Server");
  
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Hello( void)
  {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return S_OK;
  }

  Toast()
  {
    printf("Toast alive\n");
    printf("%s\n",typeid(_ClassFactoryCreatorClass).name());
  }  

  BEGIN_COM_MAP(Toast)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IClassic)
  END_COM_MAP();
  
};


OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(CLSID_CClassic,Toast);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encapsulated it in an out-of-process exe"? You need to 1) build an exe yourself of 2) use a surrogate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registering-the-dll-server-for-surrogate-activation or 3) use COM Component Services "server app" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/types-of-com--applications which is a special case of advanced surrogate

Comment: I mean using ```CAtlExeModuleT``` like this ```struct MyModule : CAtlExeModuleT<MyModule>{...}``` in file comexe.cpp and ```struct Toast : CComObjectRoot,CComCoClass<Toast,&CLSID_CClassic>,IClassic {...}``` in comobj.cpp, and link them together.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a x86 vs x64 issue?

Comment: All the exe and proxy dll and the test client are x64 .

Comment: 80040154  is really a registration issue. Use procmon from sysinternals and filter by registry access. You should see the key searched for and determine what's wrong